# Even numbers generator in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

written a small code to generate even numbers.

```
>>>even = []
>>>[even for x in range(15) if x % 2 == 0]
```

output is -  [(), (), (), (), (), (), ()]

Can the above code generate even numbers if so what is the fix ?

How can i have a block of code instead of if statement in above line, my goal is to generate prime numbers.

[prime for x in range(2,15) for y in range(1,int(x/2)) if (x%y) != 0 ..................]

Comment: [x for x in range(15) if x % 2 == 0]

Comment: Why not `list(range(0, 15, 2))`?

Comment: Can i have block of code instead of if statement, how about i want to generate a prime numbers instead of even numbers ?                            [x for x in range(2,15) for y in range(1,int(x/2)) if (x%y) != 0 ..................]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p = [q for q in range(0, 15) if not q%2]
print(p)
```

Explanation:

If q is even number then q%2 becomes `0`. So added `not` after `if`

Answer (score 2):

In your example you are adding 'even' to the list every time the if statement in the list comprehension is satisfied. This is why you get a list of empty tuples

```
[x for x in range(15) if x % 2 == 0]
```

Would be the correct implmenentation

Comment: If i want to add block of code at the if can i, lets consider i want to generate prime numbers. how can i work with this.                                                                        
     [x for x in range(2,max) for y in range(2,x) if (x%y) == 0 ....]

Answer (score 2):

If you need a *generator*, it is built in the `range` function in Python3:

```
range(0, 15, 2)
```

is an immutable sequence  that contains all even integers below 15

In Python 2, `range` returns a true list, so it may meet your requirements or not. In any case, you can use a comprehension to define a true generator:

```
( x for x in range(0, 15, 2) )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
even = [ x for x in range(15) if x%2 == 0]
```

Just a list comprehension

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way to generate even numbers

```
filter(lambda x : x % 2, range(0, 15))
```